# SAS_State Space Model

Tags: sas

I want to ask a question related State Space procedure. I have a huge dataset that contains a million groups. I need to find permanent and transitory components of each group by using State Space Model. I run the following code:

```
 proc ucm data=work;
 model price;
 by group;
 irregular plot=smooth;
 level checkbreak plot=smooth;
 estimate plot=residual;
 forecast plot=forecasts lead=10 alpha=0.5;
 run;
```

This code works well. I have just one issue. As I have a huge number of groups, it takes a lot of time (approximately 3 months). Do you know any way/method that I can use to increase the efficiency and reduce the time.
Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: You're producing 1 million plots as part of the output of this? Do you need all of those?

Comment: Yes, I need all of them. Actually, I will use the specific code to create the output as a table. So, firstly I find the permanent and transitory component and then create a table.

Comment: Do you need the graphical output or just the tables?

Comment: My full code is following:                                                                              ods trace on;

ods select ParameterEstimates;

ods output ParameterEstimates=myEstimates;

proc ucm data=work;
 model price;
 by group;
 irregular plot=smooth;
 level checkbreak plot=smooth;
 estimate plot=residual;
 forecast plot=forecasts lead=10 alpha=0.5;
run;

proc print data=myEstimates;
run;

proc transpose data=myEstimates(keep=group component estimate)
               out=transposedEstimates;
  by group;
  id component;
run;

Comment: So, I can create the table by using the above mentioned codes. However, the issue is proc ucm code takes a lot time.

Comment: This is an Unobserved Components model, not a state space model. This is expected behavior with so many groups, especially since UCM models are more complex than ARIMA. If you want to greatly improve performance, you will need a bigger server cluster and SAS Forecast Server. FS will give you high performance forecasting that is scalable in distributed environments. Your plots are also going to cause huge slowdowns, since that is a lot of extra code SAS is writing. You also will want to print the log to an external location so it isn't displaying in the internal log.

Comment: Is `3 months` accurate?  I can't imagine a computer running a program constantly that long.  90 days??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PROC UCM` allows you to output parameter estimates & forecast tables without any ODS output. UCM is a computationally expensive model on its own, and plotting every forecast by group will greatly tax the system. Instead, disable any output from `PROC UCM` with `noprint`, create two `out` tables containing estimates & forecasts, and print the log externally.

Depending on the size of your data, you may want to consider looking into [Forecast Server](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/forecast/14.1/hpfug.pdf), which is designed to solve this very problem with a high degree of accuracy and efficiency. There are some forecasting problems with such a high number of groups or observations that specialized tools will vastly improve both your models and time spent making them.

Try using the below code instead:

```
/* Print log externally */
proc printto log="C:\Log\Location\Here\log.txt" new;
run;

/* Create UCM with forecast & estimate output:
    - myForecast
    - myEstimates
*/
proc ucm data=work 
         outfor=myForecast
         outest=myEstimates
         noprint
         ;
    by group;
    model price;
    irregular;
    level checkbreak;
    estimate;
    forecast lead=10 alpha=0.5;
run;

/* Reset log to be internal */
proc printto log=log;
run;

proc print data=myEstimates;
run;

proc print data=myForecast;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The high view is Time ~ 1 / Resources and Resources ~ Money.

Your anecdotal processing rate is 463 groups / hour.

- What is your goal for time reduction ?
- What hardware are you using ?

  - Have you watched performance meters ?
  - Is memory fully used ? If yes, you might add more RAM.
  - Is CPU fully utilized on all cores ? If yes, you might add more machines -- This could mean more money if you don't have the machines or SAS license for additional installs.  If no, you can run additional SAS sessions to work on different sets of groups (call these partitions)
- Try partitioning the runs to process K groups at a time.

  - Sometimes ODS output is the bottleneck and it takes a long time to append new results to the active ODS stream.
  - Coding experiments should have a plan that includes benchmarking performance
  - With N machines working on the data, each could work on their own partition.